# Android Wear - Enable / Disable Ambient mode Programmatically

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have in the past developed some small Android Apps, and have recently gotten an LG G Watch, and absolutely love it.

Right now, the only issue with the device is that it lasts about a day and a half in ambient mode.

What I am looking to be able to do is through software, enable and disable the ambient mode on the device. In doing this, we will be able to turn it off at specific times, i.e. at night.

The advantage of being able to do this is both save the display, and by turning ambient mode off at night, I only need to charge the device every other day, but it is just an inconvenience to enable / disable every day.

I have the Java / Android experience to build the app, but the question I have is essentially the whole thing:

> How can I, in code, enable and disable ambient mode?

Is this possible? I spent some time googling, and been unable to find an answer. Has anyone used the wearable API? And is there anything in it that would allow something like this?

Comment: did you find any answer from your research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable ambient mode programatically. However, you don't need to do what you are describing. The device detects that is not worn and after 30 minutes it will turn the screen off completely, including turning off ambient mode.

Comment: I know I am late, but I was really hoping for another answer. I would still like to take control of it. My watch does not always seem to go to sleep...

Answer (score 0):

If you are a AOSP programmer, modify `AmbientService` to call `finish()` from `AmbientDream`, if you are a app programmer, sorry there's no API for what you want.