# Always-on-screen setting on WearOS

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to set the always-on-screen settings on WearOS app using the Setting provider ?
I try the doze_enabled but it doesn't work.

[image: Settings UI]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is still no way of enabling/disabling the always-on-screen setting directly from an app.

[This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28554266) (from a Google engineer) also indicates that it never has been possible, and probably never will be.

The recommended approach is to trigger an intent that takes the user to the Display page in Settings:

```
fun openDisplaySettings() {
    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

The user has to toggle the switch manually before returning to your app.

Comment: is there a way to GET the 'always-on screen' Display user setting (on or off), before triggering that intent?